# How to send Flash SMS using Camel-SMPP component

Tags: apache-camel, smpp, jbossfuse, jsmpp

I am using camel-smpp (one of the components of Apache camel) in my application to send SMS and Flash SMS to mobile phones.

I can successfully send send SMS through my application.

I have to set the parameter MessageClass.CLASS0  to my ongoing message for sending it as FLASH SMS. I am not finding relevant camel-smpp header to set the parameter. May I know what is the header to setting the MessageClass.CLASS0 parameter.

Regards,

Bharani Ravi Kanth R

Comment: Can you please improve your question (be more clear, correct the spelling, add more informations) ?

Comment: I have modified the question please give a look